# Dynamic Type Casting of Inputs

Tags: apex, data-types

I am using apex:input on a VisualForce page to take in a variety of input types. I store values separately for Dates, DateTimes and Strings, as they have their own input 'types.' However, for numeric types and certain types of string (URL, E-mail) I was hoping I could do dynamic casting. Do something like this in the controller:

```
public Object numInput{get;set}

    public String fieldType
    {
        get
        {
            return String.valueOf(field.getDescribe().getType()).toUpperCase();
        } 
        set;
    }

public void castInput()
{
    castValue = typeCast(fieldType, numInput);
}
```

Where typeCast is a fictional function that casts the second input to the type indicated by the first. This would work rather like casting an SObject, only for primitive types. Does this functionality exist?

Answer (score 4):

It does, do a certain extent.

You are actually using the function that you need in the code block above - `valueOf`
This function is available on many system types - including Decimal and Integer.

Constructing a URL or a SingleEmailMessage is more difficult, as you'll need to parse the input to get the pieces you need.

If you have the name of the type you need to construct, you can use the `Type` object to help you make a new object, eg:

```
Type t = Type.forName('YourClassName');

if(t == null) {
    //probably a good idea to check if your type exists
}
//create an instance
Object instance = t.newInstance();

instance.valueOf(value);
```

The last line causes problems, unfortunately, as you need to cast the newly created object to your desired type - and I can't see a way to do this.
So you may still need those if statements...

Comment: Yes, but how do I do this dynamically? So if I have the string name of the type I want to convert to- which could be Decimal, Integer, etc. how do I convert to that without using an if statement for each type?

Comment: Well, I didn't know about the Type.forName() function, so we've made progress. I'll play around with that and see if I can get something equivalent to the last line that works. If/when I do, I'll update here and mark the answer. Thanks for your help.